# Using update with Left Join BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join, updates

I am trying to write an Update query with LEFT JOIN in BigQuery but I am not sure how to write it.

```
  update Table1
  set ColumnTest =  ifnull(b.value, 'no run')
  From left join  (select distinct ID,value FROM Table2 where value = 10) B  --
  where Table1.ID= Table2.ID
```

I have 2 tables Table1 and Table2

I want to update Table1.ColumnTest with Table2.Value where Table1.ID= Table2.ID
and if Table1 <> Table2 then update Table1.ColumnTest with 'no run'

Thanks!!

New Try

```
  UPDATE Table1
  SET LP = IFNULL(t2.value, 'no run')
  FROM (     select distinct hits.eventInfo.eventCategory as ID, value
       FROM Table2
       CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits) AS hits
       left join  TAble1 using (hits.eventInfo.eventCategory)
       WHERE) t2
 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Error:  Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update Table1.ColumnTest with Table2.Value where Table1.ID= Table2.ID and if Table1 <> Table2 then update Table1.ColumnTest with 'no run'

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
UPDATE `table1` t1
SET ColumnTest = IFNULL(value, 'no run')
FROM (
  SELECT id, value
  FROM `table1`
  LEFT JOIN `table2`
  USING(id) 
) t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. I have added edited my post to reflect the changes you suggested and the error. Will appreciate your help

Comment: This is/was not part of your initial question and now it has obviously different issue! Please post it as new question with all relevant details and we will be happy to help :o)

Comment: I have posted it as a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890475/using-update-with-left-join-and-cross-join-bigquery. Thanks for you help

Comment: i see it  - but it is too messy - I recommend you to double check and correct the query that you presented there - it makes no sense to me as it is now